# C# ASP.NET : show an error message using validations

Tags: c#

I want to show validation errors when someone doesn't follow my validation rules (such as too few characters for a first name) or an error when they leave the field empty.

This is an example from my `User.cs` model class that is showing an error:

```
[Required(ErrorResponse= "Please do not leave first name field empty")]
[MinLength(4, ErrorResponse = "First name min length is 4")]
public string Firstname { get; set; }
```

The error I am getting:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ErrorResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MinLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute?view=net-5.0) doesn't have a `ErrorResponse` property. I see `ErrorMessage` property instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it was just a variable that could be called anything.I tried to click the check mark to mark it as answered for some reason not letting me.